# How to do kernel density estimation for data stored in polar system?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I want to do a kernel density estimation for a wind speed dataset. 
The data are stored in `speed` and `angle`, like this

```
speed direction
15 220
23 210
17 200
```

The directions are sectored into 10 degrees.

I want to know how can I do a kernel density estimation for this?

If I directly change the data into `X-Y` panel, the points would look like:
[image]

And the KDE result would look like this:

[image]

Obviously, the `peaks` of the kde result are due to the `sectored angles`. How can I get a smoothed kde result, like this?

[image]

UPDATE:
After randomize angles:
[image]

Comment: You could add some jitter to the directions, perhaps $\varepsilon \sim U[-5^\circ,5^\circ]$ uniformly distributed.

Comment: @Henry, I tried that, but I think there should still be room for improvment. You can see the resutl in my update.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for the benefit of anyone finding this now, KDEs have an association *bandwidth*, which is something you can adjust.  Increasing the bandwidth smooths the plot.  How to adjust this will depend on the plotting package you are using, and many will apply some rule to choose a best guess if you don't specify it yourself.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#Bandwidth_selection

Here's a 1D example of the effect of changing bandwidth, from that Wikipedia page.
[image: Comparison of kde of 1D distributions with various bandwidths]

In the case of the original question, if the original data is available that is not yet divided into 10 degree bins then that would avoid creating the spikes.  That would be the best data to provide to the kde function.